# iPad Cropping Issue

Tags: css, ipad

I have developed my website width of 1020px.

However when I try and access the site from an iPad it crops the website out from the right side.

How can I make it zoom out and show the entire site?

I have tried different meta viewport tags but it doesn’t help.

Comment: Out of curiosity why did you choose a width of 1020px for your website? 1024 is still a popular resolution with lots of users and setting the width of your site to 1020 won't allow room for scrollbars on desktop sites. This is why you see the majority of fixed width sites being 960 or 980 in width.

Comment: Stubborn designer, did tell him the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad 3's (and other 2x pixel density devices) misbehave with viewports. Have you tried setting the viewport to 1020px?

Something like this should work:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1020px"/>
```

Comment: I think it worked. I'm trusting the iOS Simulator for this :)